# How to display string and variable in same thing?

Tags: racket

I want the output to be like this: `abc 15`

The code:

```
(define b 15)
(if (> b 14)
(display "abc" b) 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

You could use `display` more than once:

```
(when (> b 14)
  (display "abc ")
  (display b))
```

You could use `printf`:

```
(when (> b 14)
  (printf "abc ~a" b))
```

You could use at-expressions:

```
#lang at-exp racket

(when (> b 14)
  (display @~a{abc @b}))
```